# After URL update script can't inject

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

After follow some steps on Internet and read a lot of questions, I got stucked.

**My problem is:** I want to "update" the actual tab url and after this inject a script to access and work with the DOM (of this new updated url). The first part (update the url) works fine, but, when I execute the second part (inject the script to manipulate the DOM) I got an error:

*Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "https://www.website.com/newurl/". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.*

I've checked my manifest.json but everything seems ok. Yes, I want to do this in the event "click" on a button inside the popup.html. And, yes, I'm using jQuery.

My background.js and script.js are working fine and I think that is nothing to change there.

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Test 1",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Tests.",
"background" : {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
},
"permissions": [
    "activeTab", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
],
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://*/*", "http://*/*"],
    "js": ["js/jquery.js", "js/script.js"]
}],
"icons": {
    "16": "images/icon16.png"
}
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/popup.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <button id="open">Open new URL!</button>
    <button id="start">Start!</button>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popup.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
$("#open").on("click", function(){

  chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tab) {
      chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "https://www.website.com/newurl/"});
  });

  $("#start").on("click", function(){
      chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tab) {
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            file: 'js/action/inject.js'
          }); 
      });
  });

});
```

The error occurs when I click in the "start" button.

**Important:** When I remove the "update url" step, the "start" button working fine, with no problems.

Comment: I'm testing the extension in my local computer. I can access the DOM of "https://www.website.com" easily, but, when I update the URL via extension, and try to get the DOM, I got the error.

Comment: No. The extension is at my local computer, but the website is at the internet.

Comment: After your comment I've tried this, but with no success :(

Comment: I can't reproduce. I've just made a simple extension that does exactly the same: it updates the active tab to www.example.com and injects a content script successfully.

Comment: Really? Have a jsfiddle of that? Or a paste bin? You tried in your local computer?

Comment: What do you mean by `tried in your local computer`? There's no other way to try. Here it is: https://puu.sh/uGb9k/ca2bdd1203.zip

Comment: Interesting, I tested your example here and really works, but I can't inject jQuery (via manifest). Got the "$" error.

Comment: I can't really see what you're doing there, you know...